# SQL Request can't be parse correctyle with sqlparse

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I have a big request and i try to parse it with a python program, using sqlparse.

Here is the code:

```
import sqlparse

req1 = """select qty, end_date from ITEMS as (q,e)
where iId = iid
if ((q-qty) == 0){
  update ITEMS set end_date = now,qty = q-qty
  where iId = iid
}else {
  update ITEMS set qty = q-qty
  where iId = iid
} insert into BUY_NOW values (uid,iid,qty)"""

res = sqlparse.parse(req1)
cpt = 0
for i in res[0].tokens:
    print (i)
    cpt+=1
    print(cpt)
```

Here is the output:

```
select
1

2
qty, end_date
3

4
from
5

6
ITEMS as (q,e)
7


8
where iId = iid
if ((q-qty) == 0){
  update ITEMS set end_date = now,qty = q-qty
  where iId = iid
}else {
  update ITEMS set qty = q-qty
  where iId = iid
} insert 
9
into
10

11
BUY_NOW
12

13
values
14

15
(uid,iid,qty)
16
```

So as you can see, it looks like the middle part the request if is not parsed at all.
Is it possible that the middle part is not correct sql ? I don't have the databases so i can't try it, i only have the request.
Or do you think the problem comes from sqlparse ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

That sql looks fishy to me but I'm not that smart.

You don't have to have the database to try it out though. If it's meant to work with say, MySQL, then you could quickly whip up a couple of tables with the right column names and then see if MySQL howls if you try to execute that query. I don't think you'd even need trial data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to run it, but it doesn't work. I think it's suppose to work with postgresql, but even with postegresql it doesn't seem to work. It's weird because my teacher gave me this request and he said it was working for him. I'll keep looking into it

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlparse

def extract_column_info(sql_query):
    parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql_query)

    column_info = []

    for statement in parsed:
        for token in statement.tokens:
            if token.ttype == sqlparse.tokens.Name:
                # Column name found
                column_name = token.value

                # Find the table/view associated with the column
                origin_source = find_origin_source(parsed, column_name)

                # Append the column name and its origin source to the result
                column_info.append((column_name, origin_source))

    return column_info

def find_origin_source(parsed, column_name):
    # Iterate over parsed tokens to find the source of the column
    for statement in parsed:
        for token in statement.tokens:
            if token.ttype == sqlparse.tokens.Name and token.value.upper() == column_name.upper():
                # If the column is found, look for the source table/view
                source_token = token.get_parent_name()
                if source_token:
                    return source_token.value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your SQL query goes here
    your_sql_query = """
    -- Your SQL query here
    """

    result = extract_column_info(your_sql_query)

    # Print the result as two columns: column names and their origin sources
    for column_name, origin_source in result:
        print(f"Column Name: {column_name}, Origin Source: {origin_source}")
```